# continuous spectrum of the self-adjoint Schrödinger Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, schwartz-space

I have following problem.

Take $A= - f'' + uf $ an unbounded operator with $u \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ being the Schwartz class. The domain of $A$ is $H^2(\mathbb{R})$.

(i) Show that A is self-adjoint.

(ii) Show that the continuous spectrum of A is $[0,\infty)$

To show that A is self adjoint I tried using Rellich-Kato and split A into two sections showing that one is self adjoint and the other symmetric. I got stuck trying to show that $B = -f''$ is self adjoint.

For the second part I need to find all the values $\lambda$ such that $A-\lambda I$ is injective and has dense range but is not surjective. I am not sure how to approach this in the best way.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are you stuck proving that $B$ is self-adjoint ?! :o

Comment: I took a closer look and the self-adjointness was actually easy. I am still stuck at the second part though. Could you give me any idea?